# How it is possible to add element of List in List of Integer in Java

Tags: java

I am confused with this behavior of Array List.
Can someone please explain this

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add(1);
list.add("test");

List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>();
integerList.add(123);
integerList.add(456);
integerList.addAll(list);

System.out.println(integerList);
```

How can I add String in Integer arrayList
Can someone please share some resource to understand these things?

Comment: It works because Java doesn't check the list at runtime, and `list` was declared with a raw type, which basically lets you bypass compile time checks for generics-related stuff. You should have gotten a warning, though.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @user.
But I didn't see any warning there. I am very confused with this.
Can you please explain this is more details.

Comment: I get a warning on this line of your code: `integerList.addAll(list);` Are you saying that you don't get a warning for that line?

Comment: @SauravDudeja Here, the details: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2770692/12323248)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is discussed here: [Are generics removed by the compiler at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253174/are-generics-removed-by-the-compiler-at-compile-time)

Generics are checked by the compiler, but not afterwards during runtime.

As @user mentioned, your compiler/IDE will most likely show a warning e.g.

> List is a raw type. References to generic type List should be parameterized

Comment: Why does the compiler warn `integerList.addAll(list);`, not an error?

Comment: Because the first `ArrayList` is declared with a raw type. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2770692/12323248.
If the first line would be typed instead like `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();` or `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();` then the compiler would safely indicate an error as soon you try to add another type.